# Products Sort Order in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

On the category page of my Magento website:
http://www.knifeindia.com/brands/cold-steel.html the products are in a certain order. However, clicking on any product - and hitting the browser's back button reveals a completely new order of products in a way it is really difficult to locate where I left off.
Experiencing this problem only for certain categories and not all.

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears you have a combination of parameters, ajax sorting your product listing so as you navigate forward the ajax sort isn't saved when you go back.

You could investigate a way to align your sort functionality to be always parameter based so its preserved as you navigate forward and return back to where you were ( with parameters in your url ).